# Eslint react/prop-types error with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm getting the Eslint error: `'age' is missing in props validation eslint (react/prop-types)` when using `extends` for interface for React components using the below seemingly valid example:

```
interface SuperProps {
  age: number;
}

interface TestProps extends SuperProps {
  name: string;
}

const Test = ({ name, age }: TestProps) => {
  return (
    <p>
      {name}: {age}
    </p>
  );
};
```

Is this a bug or a feature that I haven't fully grasped?

Comment: I believe it to be a bug in package "eslint-plugin-react", because that's a completely valid interface and it should work just fine, but the plugin can't find the props defined in the parent interface.

Comment: @TelmoTrooper - you're probably right, found this issue that I think is the correct one: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2654 Strange that this could pass through the checkpoints without being noticed, it should be a common enough pattern.

Comment: Since you are using TS probably there's not need to use `eslint` checks for prop types and it can be disabled in `.eslintrc` this way: `"react/prop-types": "off"'`

Comment: Thanks, not really solving the issue. Seems though that the issue has been closed and I haven't tested the functionality lately.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, as mentioned in the question comments there was an issue raised regarding this validation rule here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2654.

The issue is closed but it seems it is not resolved.
The validation rule can be disabled by adding

`'react/require-default-props': 0`

to the rules in your `eslintrc.js` file